# How many ways can you order the matches in a round robin tournament with 2N teams?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to figure out how many possibilities there are for arranging the matches in a round robin tournament with $2N$ teams, where each team plays each other exactly once.

There will therefore be $2N-1$ rounds, and $\frac{2N(2N-1)}{2}=N(2N-1)$ total pairings. The number of ways of ordering these pairings will be reduced greatly from $(N(2N-1))!$ due to the additional constraint of each team appearing exactly once in each round.

I've worked out that for the first round, there are $$\frac{(2N)!}{2^N\cdot N!}$$ ways to pair up the teams (number of ways to order the teams divided by number of ways of ordering the pairs and divided by number of ways of ordering the teams within the pairs).

For the second round onwards, where each team now has a restricted pool of other teams to choose from, I'm a little stumped, however. I'll outline my thoughts so far - the rest of the post will just be me stating what I've attempted.

You can alternatively work out the number of possible first-round pairings in the following way:

Choose 1 of $\frac{2N(2N-1)}{2}$ possible pairings.

Now there are $2N-2$ teams to choose from, leading to $\frac{(2N-2)(2N-3)}{2}$ possible pairings for the second pair, $\frac{(2N-4)(2N-5)}{2}$ possible pairings for the third pair, and so on.

So you have $\prod_{n=0}^N\frac{(2N-2n)(2N-2n-1)}{2}=\frac{(2N)!}{2^N}$ possible sets of pairings, then divide by the number of ways you can arrange the pairings, which is ${N!}$, leading to our nice $\frac{(2N)!}{2^N\cdot N!}$ expression.

The second round is more complicated - taking the simple case $2N=6$:

Take a first round of $$\{t_1,t_2\}, \{t_3,t_4\}, \{t_5,t_6\}$$

You can now choose from one of $$\frac{2N(2N-1)}{2}-N = \frac{2N(2N-2)}{2}$$ pairings, as we can't choose pairings that appeared in the first round.

For the second pairing in the second round, I have no idea how to formulate which pairings you can choose from - obviously you have $N+1$ pairings excluded from having been picked already, and some more from containing teams that appear in the first second round pairing, but then you also have, for example:

If you pick

$$\{t_1,t_3\}$$

as your first second round pairing, you can't then choose

$$\{t_2,t_4\}$$

as that leaves no valid final pairings, as $\{t_5,t_6\}$ has already occurred in round 1.

How do you proceed?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A289747

Comment: That's a useful result but I would love to know how to get there!